# Combing two result set

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to combine two result set i have used union and union all but no luck

Result set 1

| Number1 |
| --- |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |

Result set 2

| Number2 |
| --- |
| 13 |
| 55 |
| 60 |
| 80 |

Output

| Number1 | Number2 |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | 13 |
| 15 | 55 |
| 16 | 60 |
| 17 | 80 |

Comment: Which RDMBS are you actually using MySQL, Oracle, or both?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a column to join them on.  In Oracle, you can just use `rownum` and then `join`:

```
select r1.number1, r2.number2
from (select r1.number1, rownum as seqnum
      from results1 r1
     ) r1 full join
     (select r2.number2, rownum as seqnum
      from results2 r2
     ) r2
     using (seqnum)
```

Comment: Sir I am using oracle